# What does the metric "data size" (in Exchange step) represent in the Spark UI's SQL tab?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What does the following 55.7 TB represent ?

[image]

If it is the size of the shuffle output files on disk, then what does represent the metric displayed as "Shuffle Write" in UI's *Jobs* tab for the given stage:
[image]

For *"data size"*, the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/web-ui.html#sql-metrics) says *"the size of broadcast/shuffled/collected data of the operator (BroadcastExchange, ShuffleExchange, Subquery)"* which is not that clear...

Is it something like the size of uncompressed (lz4 algorithm by default) files ?

Thanks !

Note: Screenshots have been taken once the stage completed.